# Changing visibility of HTML elements based on geolocation permission

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an HTML element visible if the end user hasn't agreed to let the browser know their location. However, my current code isn't working (nor is the `console log`) when declining the browser's request. But when allowing the browser to access my location, the API call to Google Places works.

To summarise: If a user declines the browser's request, I want the `visibility` of `geolocationunavail` to be `visible`, rather than `hidden`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="geolocationunavail"> 
    <p>Don't want to share your location?</p>
    <p><span>That's cool.</span> Type a location below.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#geolocationunavail {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
function getUserLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            document.querySelector("#longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;
            document.querySelector("#latitude").value = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var lat = position.coords.latitude; 
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert(status);
                }
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results);
                    var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
                    document.querySelector("#citysearch").value = address;
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        document.getElementById("geolocationunavail").style.display = "visible";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 different problems, so I will address them both:

First, your geolocation function is not working as expected. This is happening because you are not using the function correctly. You would not want to use an else statement to say that geolocation is not working, because geolocation will always "work" since it is called successfully regardless of the user input. Even if the user selects "block" the function technically "worked" and therefore will not run the else statement.

Second, your visibility is not toggling correctly. There are 2 ways you can fix this. You can either make it a class and use `classList.toggle("myClass")`, or you can do `document.getElementById('geolocationunavil').style.visibility = 'visible';`

Both of these put together will result in:

```
function getUserLocation() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
        document.querySelector("#longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;
        document.querySelector("#latitude").value = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var lat = position.coords.latitude; 
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                alert(status);
            }
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results);
                var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
                document.querySelector("#citysearch").value = address;
            }
        });
    },
    err => {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        document.getElementById("geolocationunavail").style.visibility = "visible";
    })
}
```